# What is the role of the {} in type_trait<T>{} when used in a template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, types, template-meta-programming, type-traits

I'm often seeing occurrences of this `{}` in templated code. I'm not sure I understand what's it doing. For example:

```
std::enable_if_t<std::is_copy_constructible<T&>{} && !std::is_same<T, MyClass>{}>>
```

What is `{}` here? Is it instantiating the type? What does that mean as a template parameter?

AFAIK instantiating a type means creating an object. How can you create an object in this context? Is it just creating a dummy object? And why do that? What is the meaning and purpose of this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this context, `type_trait<T>{}` is equivalent to `type_trait<T>::value`. Your example is equivalent to the following:

```
std::enable_if_t<std::is_copy_constructible<T&>::value && !std::is_same<T, MyClass>::value>>
```

In general, some benefits of using `type_trait<T>{}` instead of `type_trait<T>::value` are:

- C++17 added `type_trait_v<T>`. Prior to C++17, `type_trait<T>{}` is just as terse.
- `type_trait<T>{}` works with tag dispatch. That is to say, `foo(type_trait<T>{})` can call different overloads based on the value of `type_trait<T>::value` because the true and false values are distinct types.

---

This works because type traits inherit from `std::integral_constant<bool, Value>` which has a [`constexpr operator bool()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant#Member_functions) which returns the value. Thus, `std::is_copy_constructible<T&>{}` produces a value of type `std::is_copy_constructible<T&>`, but since we are using it in a context that expects a `bool`, the implicit conversion operator is called.